# What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set-difference

Let `A` and `B` be two sets. I'm looking for *really* fast or elegant ways to compute the set difference (`A - B` or `A \B`, depending on your preference) between them. The two sets are stored and manipulated as Javascript arrays, as the title says.

Notes:

- Gecko-specific tricks are okay
- I'd prefer sticking to native functions (but I am open to a lightweight library if it's way faster)
- I've seen, but not tested, [JS.Set](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/set.html) (see previous point)

**Edit:** I noticed a comment about sets containing duplicate elements. When I say "set" I'm referring to the mathematical definition, which means (among other things) that they do not contain duplicate elements.

Comment: What is this "set difference" terminology you are using?  Is that from C++ or something?

Comment: What are in your sets? Depending on the type you are targetting (eg Numbers), computing a set difference can be done *really* fast and elegant. If your sets contain (say) DOM elements, you're going to be stuck with a slow `indexOf` implementation.

Comment: @Crescent: my sets contain numbers - sorry for not specifying. @Josh: it's the standard set operation in mathematics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Complements)

Comment: @JoshStodola that's the [mathematical notation for set difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Complements)

Comment: TC39 proposal is currently Stage 2: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-set-methods

Answer (score 230, accepted):

I don't know if this is most effective, but perhaps the shortest:

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var B = [1, 3, 4, 7];

var diff = A.filter(function(x) {
  return B.indexOf(x) < 0;
});

console.log(diff); // [2]
```

Updated to ES6:

```js
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const B = [1, 3, 4, 7];

const diff = A.filter(x => !B.includes(x));

console.log(diff); // [2]
```

Comment: Note: array.filter is not supported cross-browser (e.g. not in IE). It seems not to matter to @Matt since he stated that "Gecko-specific tricks are okay" but I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: This is very slow. O(|A| * |B|)

Comment: @EricBréchemier This is now supported (since IE 9). [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a standard ECMAScript feature.

Comment: what is "ES6"  ? I found this syntax don't work on safari 9.1  (on 10.0 its ok)

Comment: @PaoloBiavati ES6 is [ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) 6th edition. It's the standardization of JavaScript. The 6th edition was published in June 2015. I'm not familiar with Safari's versions, but it's likely version 9.1 didn't support the syntactic sugar form of lambda functions (the "=>" operator) whereas version 10 does.

Comment: it's working for more than one itme also   . A = [200000340755,200000340767, 200000340760];
B = [200000340755];

diff = A.filter(function(x) { return B.indexOf(x) < 0 })

console.log(diff);

Comment: In ES6, you could use [`!B.includes(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead of `B.indexOf(x) < 0` :)

Comment: This doesn't work when computing difference of arrays containing objects - ie: `[{a: 5}, {b: 6}].filter(x => [{a: 5}].indexOf(x) < 0 )` gives `[{a: 5}, {b: 6}]`

Comment: @glebm That would only be true if `indexOf` would run a linear search, but benchmarks suggest that it's somehow indexed. It's pretty much as fast as a key lookup in an object.

Comment: @glebm I don't think this kind of problem can be solved in linear time at all, it will always be polynomial, unless you solved the P vs NP problem.

Comment: @WongJiaHau This can be done in amortized `O(|A| + |B|)` with hash sets.

Comment: This works for integers but will fail for strings. `'himom'.includes('hi') === true`

Answer (score 183):

Well, 7 years later, with [ES6's Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) object it's quite easy (but still not as compact as [python's](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-difference/) `A - B`), and reportedly faster than `indexOf` for large arrays:

```js
console.clear();

let a = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let b = new Set([5, 4, 3, 2]);

let a_minus_b = new Set([...a].filter(x => !b.has(x)));
let b_minus_a = new Set([...b].filter(x => !a.has(x)));
let a_intersect_b = new Set([...a].filter(x => b.has(x))); 
let a_union_b = new Set([...a, ...b]); 

console.log(...a_minus_b);     // {1}
console.log(...b_minus_a);     // {5}
console.log(...a_intersect_b); // {2,3,4}
console.log(...a_union_b);     // {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Comment: Also considerably faster than indexOf for large arrays.

Answer (score 23):

Looking at a lof of these solutions, they do fine for small cases.  But, when you blow them up to a million items, the time complexity starts getting silly.

```
 A.filter(v => B.includes(v))
```

That starts looking like an O(N^2) solution.  Since there is an O(N) solution, let's use it, you can easily modify to not be a generator if you're not up to date on your JS runtime.

```js
    function *setMinus(A, B) {
      const setA = new Set(A);
      const setB = new Set(B);

      for (const v of setB.values()) {
        if (!setA.delete(v)) {
            yield v;
        }
      }

      for (const v of setA.values()) {
        yield v;
      }
    }

    a = [1,2,3];
    b = [2,3,4];

    console.log(Array.from(setMinus(a, b)));
```

While this is a bit more complex than many of the other solutions, when you have large lists this will be far faster.

Let's take a quick look at the performance difference, running it on a set of 1,000,000 random integers between 0...10,000 we see the following performance results.

```
setMinus time =  181 ms
    diff time =  19099 ms
```

```js
function buildList(count, range) {
  result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * range))
  }
  return result;
}

function *setMinus(A, B) {
  const setA = new Set(A);
  const setB = new Set(B);

  for (const v of setB.values()) {
    if (!setA.delete(v)) {
        yield v;
    }
  }

  for (const v of setA.values()) {
    yield v;
  }
}

function doDiff(A, B) {
  return A.filter(function(x) { return B.indexOf(x) < 0 })
}

const listA = buildList(100_000, 100_000_000); 
const listB = buildList(100_000, 100_000_000); 

let t0 = process.hrtime.bigint()

const _x = Array.from(setMinus(listA, listB))

let t1 = process.hrtime.bigint()

const _y = doDiff(listA, listB)

let t2 = process.hrtime.bigint()

console.log("setMinus time = ", (t1 - t0) / 1_000_000n, "ms");
console.log("diff time = ", (t2 - t1) / 1_000_000n, "ms");
```

Comment: Note that if you have a really large Set, you're limited to 2^24 items (16,777,216) and it will crash. Otherwise, this is a great solution!

Comment: @koblas your second code snippet is broken and throws a ReferenceError yet you reverted an edit I made fixing said issue

Comment: `process.hrtime.bigint()` is a nodejs function, not a browser function and will not work in the "run code snippet" engine. The difference is in nanosecond vs millisecond timing.

Comment: That setMinus() function doesn't looks correct to be a A-B diff. Elements of B not in A should not be returned. Implemented as it is, it's a set xor rather than a diff.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using `Set`s, it can be quite simple and performant:

```js
function setDifference(a, b) {
  return new Set(Array.from(a).filter(item => !b.has(item)));
}
```

Since `Set`s use Hash functions* under the hood, the `has` function is much faster than `indexOf` (this matters if you have, say, more than 100 items).

Answer (score 14):

You can use an object as a map to avoid linearly scanning `B` for each element of `A` as in [user187291's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javascr/1723220#1723220):

```
function setMinus(A, B) {
    var map = {}, C = [];

    for(var i = B.length; i--; )
        map[B[i].toSource()] = null; // any other value would do

    for(var i = A.length; i--; ) {
        if(!map.hasOwnProperty(A[i].toSource()))
            C.push(A[i]);
    }

    return C;
}
```

The non-standard [`toSource()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Object/toSource) is used to get unique property names; if all elements already have unique string representations (as is the case with numbers), you can speed up the code by dropping the `toSource()` invocations.

Answer (score 8):

The shortest, using jQuery, is:

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var B = [1, 3, 4, 7];

var diff = $(A).not(B);

console.log(diff.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This returns an object of the difference.

Comment: jQuery `not` no longer works with generic objects as of 3.0.0-rc1. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3147

Comment: It's not a great idea to add a dependency on a ~70k 3rd party library **just** to do this, since the same thing can be accomplished in just a few lines of code as shown in the other answers here.  However, if you are already using jQuery on your project this will work just fine.

Comment: Though this approach has less code, but it does not provide any explanation of the space and time complexity of the the differ algorithms and the data structure it uses to perform the method. It is black boxed for  developers to engineer the software with no evaluation when data scale up or with limited memory is allowed. if you use such approach with large data set, the performance might remains unknown until further research onto the source code.

Comment: This is just returning the amount (2 in this case) of elements of A which are not in B. Converting 2 into array is pointless...

Answer (score 7):

Some simple functions, borrowing from @milan's answer:

```
const setDifference = (a, b) => new Set([...a].filter(x => !b.has(x)));
const setIntersection = (a, b) => new Set([...a].filter(x => b.has(x)));
const setUnion = (a, b) => new Set([...a, ...b]);
```

Usage:

```
const a = new Set([1, 2]);
const b = new Set([2, 3]);

setDifference(a, b); // Set { 1 }
setIntersection(a, b); // Set { 2 }
setUnion(a, b); // Set { 1, 2, 3 }
```

Answer (score 6):

I would hash the array B, then keep values from the array A not present in B:

```
function getHash(array){
  // Hash an array into a set of properties
  //
  // params:
  //   array - (array) (!nil) the array to hash
  //
  // return: (object)
  //   hash object with one property set to true for each value in the array

  var hash = {};
  for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    hash[ array[i] ] = true;
  }
  return hash;
}

function getDifference(a, b){
  // compute the difference a\b
  //
  // params:
  //   a - (array) (!nil) first array as a set of values (no duplicates)
  //   b - (array) (!nil) second array as a set of values (no duplicates)
  //
  // return: (array)
  //   the set of values (no duplicates) in array a and not in b, 
  //   listed in the same order as in array a.

  var hash = getHash(b);
  var diff = [];
  for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    var value = a[i];
    if ( !hash[value]){
      diff.push(value);
    }
  }
  return diff;
}
```

Comment: I think it is better to compute the diff outside of getDifference so it may be reused multiple times. Maybe optional like so: `getDifference(a, b, hashOfB)`, if not passed it will be computed otherwise it is reused as-is.

Answer (score 6):

Using [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) (Library for functional JS)

```
>>> var foo = [1,2,3]
>>> var bar = [1,2,4]
>>> _.difference(foo, bar);
[4]
```

Comment: Edit queue is currently full, but the following is helpful if a and b are already Sets: ```_.difference([...a],[...b])```

Answer (score 5):

Incorporating the idea from Christoph and assuming a couple of non-standard iteration methods on arrays and objects/hashes (`each` and friends), we can get set difference, union and intersection in linear time in about 20 lines total:

```
var setOPs = {
  minusAB : function (a, b) {
    var h = {};
    b.each(function (v) { h[v] = true; });
    return a.filter(function (v) { return !h.hasOwnProperty(v); });
  },
  unionAB : function (a, b) {
    var h = {}, f = function (v) { h[v] = true; };
    a.each(f);
    b.each(f);
    return myUtils.keys(h);
  },
  intersectAB : function (a, b) {
    var h = {};
    a.each(function (v) { h[v] = 1; });
    b.each(function (v) { h[v] = (h[v] || 0) + 1; });
    var fnSel = function (v, count) { return count > 1; };
    var fnVal = function (v, c) { return v; };
    return myUtils.select(h, fnSel, fnVal);
  }
};
```

This assumes that `each` and `filter` are defined for arrays, and that we have two utility methods:

- `myUtils.keys(hash)`: returns an
  array with the keys of the hash
- `myUtils.select(hash, fnSelector,
  fnEvaluator)`:  returns an array with
  the results of calling `fnEvaluator`
  on the key/value pairs for which
  `fnSelector` returns true.

The `select()` is loosely inspired by Common Lisp, and is merely `filter()` and `map()` rolled into one. (It would be better to have them defined on `Object.prototype`, but doing so wrecks havoc with jQuery, so I settled for static utility methods.)

Performance: Testing with

```
var a = [], b = [];
for (var i = 100000; i--; ) {
  if (i % 2 !== 0) a.push(i);
  if (i % 3 !== 0) b.push(i);
}
```

gives two sets with 50,000 and 66,666 elements. With these values A-B takes about 75ms, while union and intersection are about 150ms each. (Mac Safari 4.0, using Javascript Date for timing.)

I think that's decent payoff for 20 lines of code.

Comment: you should still check `hasOwnProperty()` even if the elements are numeric: otherwise, something like `Object.prototype[42] = true;` means `42` can never occur in the result set

Comment: Granted that it would be possible to set 42 in that way, but is there a semi-realistic use case where anyone would actually do so?
But for general strings I take the point - it could easily conflict with some Object.prototype variable or function.

Answer (score 4):

As for the fasted way, this isn't so elegant but I've run some tests to be sure.  Loading one array as an object is far faster to process in large quantities:

```
var t, a, b, c, objA;

    // Fill some arrays to compare
a = Array(30000).fill(0).map(function(v,i) {
    return i.toFixed();
});
b = Array(20000).fill(0).map(function(v,i) {
    return (i*2).toFixed();
});

    // Simple indexOf inside filter
t = Date.now();
c = b.filter(function(v) { return a.indexOf(v) < 0; });
console.log('completed indexOf in %j ms with result %j length', Date.now() - t, c.length);

    // Load `a` as Object `A` first to avoid indexOf in filter
t = Date.now();
objA = {};
a.forEach(function(v) { objA[v] = true; });
c = b.filter(function(v) { return !objA[v]; });
console.log('completed Object in %j ms with result %j length', Date.now() - t, c.length);
```

Results:

```
completed indexOf in 1219 ms with result 5000 length
completed Object in 8 ms with result 5000 length
```

However, this works with **strings only**.  If you plan to compare numbered sets you'll want to map results with **parseFloat**.

Answer (score 4):

The function below are ports of the methods found in Python's [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) class and follows the [TC39 Set methods proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-set-methods/).

```js
const
  union = (a, b) => new Set([...a, ...b]),
  intersection = (a, b) => new Set([...a].filter(x => b.has(x))),
  difference = (a, b) => new Set([...a].filter(x => !b.has(x))),
  symetricDifference = (a, b) => union(difference(a, b), difference(b, a)),
  isSubsetOf = (a, b) => [...b].every(x => a.has(x)),
  isSupersetOf = (a, b) => [...a].every(x => b.has(x)),
  isDisjointFrom = (a, b) => !intersection(a, b).size;

const
  a = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]),
  b = new Set([5, 4, 3, 2]);

console.log(...union(a, b));              // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(...intersection(a, b));       // [2, 3, 4]
console.log(...difference(a, b));         // [1]
console.log(...difference(b, a));         // [5]
console.log(...symetricDifference(a, b)); // [1, 5]

const
  c = new Set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']),
  d = new Set(['B', 'D']);
  
console.log(isSubsetOf(c, d));            // true
console.log(isSupersetOf(d, c));          // true

const
  e = new Set(['A', 'B', 'C']),
  f = new Set(['X', 'Y', 'Z']);
  
console.log(isDisjointFrom(e, f));        // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: TypeScript converted version: https://gist.github.com/Xevion/2390702004ccd756ad7e272debed9a3c

Answer (score 1):

This works, but I think another one is much more shorter, and elegant too

```
A = [1, 'a', 'b', 12];
B = ['a', 3, 4, 'b'];

diff_set = {
    ar : {},
    diff : Array(),
    remove_set : function(a) { ar = a; return this; },
    remove: function (el) {
        if(ar.indexOf(el)<0) this.diff.push(el);
    }
}

A.forEach(diff_set.remove_set(B).remove,diff_set);
C = diff_set.diff;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`core-js`](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) to polyfill the [New `Set` methods proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-set-methods):

```
import "core-js"

new Set(A).difference(B)
```

In theory, the time complexity should be `Θ(n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by @koblas is good but returns items that are in both arrays aswell. With a slight modification (in ES6) for my use case where I want to get the difference, (with the intention of retrieving new items in `array_j`, as well as the the items in `array_i` that are not in `array j` as separate output arrays, these are the 3 main ways provided to do this:

```
var arr_i = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"];
var arr_j = ["a", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "n"];
```

The answers should be the new items in array j as `['b', 'e', 'i']` as well as the items in array i that are not in array j as `['k', 'l', 'n']`

```
// Convert to Set
var set_i = new Set(arr_i);
var set_j = new Set(arr_j);

const changes = (arr1, arr2) => {
  // Using Array method
  let turn_on = arr2.filter((x) => !arr1.includes(x));
  let turn_off = arr1.filter((x) => !arr2.includes(x));
  return { turn_on, turn_off };
};

const setChanges = (set1, set2) => {
  // Using Set method
  let turn_on = new Set([...set2].filter((x) => !set1.has(x)));
  let turn_off = new Set([...set1].filter((x) => !set2.has(x)));
  return { turn_on, turn_off };
};

function* setMinus(setA, setB) {
  // Using Set method with generator by @koblas
  for (const v of setB.values()) {
    // .delete returns true if value was already in Set; otherwise false.
    if (!setA.delete(v)) {
      yield v;
    }
  }
}

const changesGenerator = (set1, set2) => {
  let turn_off = Array.from(setMinus(set2, set1));
  let turn_on = Array.from(setMinus(set1, set2));
  return { turn_on, turn_off };
};
```

All three methods return:

```
{ turn_on: [ 'k', 'l', 'n' ], turn_off: [ 'b', 'e', 'i' ] }
```

Timing these on random array including numbers from range [0,10000] containing 5000 items

```
let arr_i = Array.from({ length: 5000 }, () =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
);
let arr_j = Array.from({ length: 5000 }, () =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
);

var set_i = new Set(arr_i);
var set_j = new Set(arr_j);

console.time("Array method");
changes(arr_i, arr_j);
console.timeEnd("Array method");

console.time("Set method");
setChanges(set_i, set_j);
console.timeEnd("Set method");

console.time("Generator method");
changesGenerator(set_i, set_j);
console.timeEnd("Generator method");
```

Returns:

```
Array method: 36.894ms
Set method: 1.14ms
Generator method: 2.155ms
```

So yeah, just use:

```
let set1_minus_set2 = new Set([...set1].filter((x) => !set2.has(x)));
```