# can you remove one array from another in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have a three arrays in javascript

```
var array1 = new Array (1,2,3,4,5);
var array2 = new Array ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
var array3 = new Array ("a", "c", "d");
```

and i basically want to:

1. Create a new array with array2 minus items in array3. So it should result in

   var array4 = new Array {"b", "e"};
2. Create another array with the corresponding index of array1 that aligns with array 4, so in this case i would also want to be able to generate

   var array5 = new Array {2, 5}

i know in dotnet 3.5 there are lots of simple methods to do this operation but wasn't sure if javascript had anything similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, for starters, array declaration takes one of two forms:

```
var myArr = new Array(1, 2, 3);
// or
var myArr = [1, 2, 3];
```

The second option is better, btw. [See here for reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931872/whats-the-difference-between-array-and-while-declaring-a-javascript-arr).

What you're actually looking for is something called difference (as opposed to intersection or union). There's some other questions on Stack Overflow about array difference, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference), however the accepted solution uses `for .. in` on an array, which is not a good idea. I heard Doug Crockford literally punches you in the face *through the Internet* every time you do that. [Here's a more technical discussion about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) if you're interested.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javascr) might suit you better.

Answer (score 6):

This is made much simpler using Javascript 1.6 Array functions:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(set){return this.filter(
    function(e,i,a){return set.indexOf(e)<0}
)};
Array.prototype.mapTo = function(set,to){return this.map(
    function(e,i,a){return to[set.indexOf(e)]}
)};

var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
var array3 = ["a", "c", "d"];

var array4 = array2.remove(array3);
var array5 = array4.mapTo(array2, array1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery:

```
var array4 = $.grep(array2, function(n, i){
  return $.inArray(n, array3) == -1;
});
```

For pure JavaScript, see these questions:

- [Javascript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)
- [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javascr)

Answer (score 3):

A very short and efficient way would be if you use :

```
_.difference(array1,array2)
```

Comment: this requires lodash or some external package & you didn't even mention that!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend implementing these:
http://www.dustindiaz.com/sugar-arrays/

Makes working with arrays a whole lot easier.
The solution to your problem would then look like this:

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  array3 = ["a", "c", "d"],
  array5 = [],
  array4 = array2.filter(function(item, i) {
        var ok = array3.indexOf(item) === -1;
        if (ok) {
              array5.push(i + 1);
        }
        return ok;
  });

  alert(array4);
  alert(array5);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works only if array2 and array3 have only strings or numbers.

Step 1. Convert array3 into an object with properties (for faster lookups)

```
var obj = {}, i;
for(i=0;i<array3.length;i++) {
    obj[array3[i]] = true;
}
```

step 2: loop thru the array2 and get only the elements not in array3

```
var array4 = [], array5 = [];
for(i=0; i<array2.length;i++) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(array2[i])) {
        array4.push(array2[i]);
        array5.push(array1[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript is a compact language, by design.

if you don't have a library, and want a convenient method to work in most browsers,
you need to write some code.

```
Array.prototype.lastIndex= function(what){
 var L= this.length;
 while(L){
  if(this[--L]=== what) return L;
 }
 return -1;
}
Array.prototype.remove= function(arg){
 var what, L= arg.length, ax;
 while(L && this.length){
  what= arg[--L];
  while((ax= this.lastIndex(what))!= -1){
   this.splice(ax, 1);
  }
 }
 return this;
}


var array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], array3 = ["a", "c", "d"];
alert(array2.remove(array3))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) includes difference & map methods to simplify to this:

```
var array4 = _.difference(array2, array3);
var array5 = _.map(array4, function(i){ return array1[array2.indexOf(i)] });
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/104) really helped me:

> ```
> var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> var b = [2, 3, 4, 5];
> var c = _.without.apply(_, [a].concat(b));
> ```

```
 Result: c = [1]
```