# Javascript algorithm to find elements in array that are not in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, arrays

I'm looking for a good algorithm to get all the elements in one array that are not elements in another array.  So given these arrays:

```
var x = ["a","b","c","t"];
var ​​​​​​​​​y = [​​​​​​​"d","a","t","e","g"];
```

I want to end up with this array:

```
var z = ["d","e","g"];
```

I'm using jquery, so I can take advantage of `$.each()` and `$.inArray()`. Here's the solution I've come up with, but it seems like there should be a better way.

```
// goal is to get rid of values in y if they exist in x
var x = ["a","b","c","t"];
var y = ["d","a","t","e","g"];

var z = [];
$.each(y, function(idx, value){
  if ($.inArray(value,x) == -1) {
    z.push(value);
  }
});
​alert(z);  // should be ["d","e","g"]
```

Here is the [code in action](http://jsbin.com/axahi3/edit). Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var z = $.grep(y, function(el){return $.inArray(el, x) == -1});
```

Also, that method name is too short for its own good.  I would expect it to mean isElementInArray, not indexOf.

For a demo with objects, see http://jsfiddle.net/xBDz3/6/

Comment: hmm, well my situation has objects in my arrays, not just simple strings. I put strings in my question to simplify things. I'm not sure your solution would work.

Comment: The name grep may be misleading.  It doesn't really have anything to do with strings.  It just takes a predicate.  Other languages call the same thing filter.  I made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xBDz3/6/).

Comment: wow, after a quick test, it looks like that does work. The command grep is misleading, as I'm assuming it would work on text like the unix command. I'll do some more testing.

Comment: Note on current support of fiddle code: `JSON.stringify(z)` works in Chrome 55 where `z.toSource()` errors.

Comment: ohh la la - very nice

Answer (score 197):

in ES6 simply

```js
const a1 = ["a", "b", "c", "t"];
const a2 = ["d", "a", "t", "e", "g"];

console.log( a2.filter(x => !a1.includes(x)) );
```

(another option is `a2.filter(x => a1.indexOf(x)===-1)` )

Answer (score 78):

Late answer with the new ECMA5 javascript:

```
var x = ["a","b","c","t"];
var y = ["d","a","t","e","g"];

myArray = y.filter( function( el ) {
  return x.indexOf( el ) < 0;
});
```

Comment: Any idea on the algorithmic complexity/scalability of this?

Comment: @mikecsh Probably not good.  Sorting both first and then marching through might be better.

Comment: @ccook a proof of your statement may be useful actually. Otherwise is just a "Probably... maybe" sentence.

Answer (score 15):

Here's an alternative using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
function inAButNotInB(A, B) {
  return _.filter(A, function (a) {
    return !_.contains(B, a);
  });
}
```

Comment: I've moved away from being so dependent on jquery and am utilizing smaller libraries such as underscore and lodash. These libraries make solving problems like the original question so much easier. Thanks for including an underscore-based solution!

Answer (score 12):

I am quite late now but maybe it will be helpful for someone.

If the array is not just a simple array but an array of objects then the following can be used:

```
var arr1 = [
    {
      "prop1": "value1",
      "prop2": "value2",
    },
    {
      "prop1": "value3",
      "prop2": "value4",
    },
    {
      "prop1": "value5",
      "prop2": "value6",
    },
  ];

var arr2 = ['value1','value3', 'newValue'];

// finds all the elements of arr2 that are not in arr1
arr2.filter( 
    val => !arr1.find( arr1Obj => arr1Obj.prop1 === val)
); // outputs "newValue"
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a late answer, but it uses no libraries so some may find it helpful.

```
/**
 * Returns a non-destructive Array of elements that are not found in
 * any of the parameter arrays.
 *
 * @param {...Array} var_args   Arrays to compare.
 */
Array.prototype.uniqueFrom = function() {
  if (!arguments.length)
    return [];
  var a1 = this.slice(0); // Start with a copy

  for (var n=0; n < arguments.length; n++) {
    var a2 = arguments[n];
    if (!(a2 instanceof Array))
      throw new TypeError( 'argument ['+n+'] must be Array' );

    for(var i=0; i<a2.length; i++) {
      var index = a1.indexOf(a2[i]);
      if (index > -1) {
        a1.splice(index, 1);
      } 
    }
  }
  return a1;
}
```

Example:

```
var sheetUsers = ['joe@example.com','fred@example.com','sam@example.com'];
var siteViewers = ['joe@example.com','fred@example.com','lucy@example.com'];
var viewersToAdd = sheetUsers.uniqueFrom(siteViewers);  // [sam@example.com]
var viewersToRemove = siteViewers.uniqueFrom(sheetUsers);  // [lucy@example.com]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 findDiff = (A, B) => {
     return  A.filter(function (a) {
          return !B.includes(a);
     });
 }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 2):

Make sorted copies of the arrays first.  If the top elements are equal, remove them both.  Otherwise remove the element that is less and add it to your result array.  If one array is empty, then add the rest of the other array to the result and finish.  You can iterate through the sorted arrays instead of removing elements.

```
// assume x and y are sorted
xi = 0; yi = 0; xc = x.length; yc = y.length;
while ( xi < xc && yi < yc ) {
  if ( x[xi] == y[yi] ) {
    xi += 1;
    yi += 1;
  } else if ( x[xi] < y[yi] ) {
    z.push( x[xi] );
    xi += 1;
  } else {
    z.push( y[yi] );
    yi += 1;
  }
}
// add remainder of x and y to z.  one or both will be empty.
```

Comment: @Drawnonward: thanks for your suggestion. I understand what you are doing, but I'm wanting to shrink my code to something as simple and lightweight as possible, hopefully leveraging existing jquery code. If I run into a performance problem, I'll consider your idea.

Comment: Good does not always mean fast, but I took it that way.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

[Maybe jLinq can help you?](http://www.hugoware.net/Projects/jLinq)

It lets you run queries like this against javascript objects.

For example:

```
var users = [ { name: "jacob", age: 25 },  { name: "bob" , age: 30 }]
var additionalusers = [ { name: "jacob", age: 25 },  { name: "bill" , age: 25 }]

var newusers = jLinq.from(users).except(additionalusers).select();

>>> newusers = [ { name: "bob" , age: 30 } ]
```

It's a bit overkill for you at the moment, but it's a robust solution that I was glad to learn about.

It can do intersects, unions, handle boolean logic and all kinds of great linq style goodness.

Comment: great looking library, haven't seen that one yet. Still probably a bit much for my immediate needs, but I'll probably give it a whirl for some other things I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### There is a [*TC-39 Proposal for Set Methods*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-set-methods), currently in *Stage 3 (as of Sep 2023)*

You can accomplish this with the [`Set.prototype.difference`](https://tc39.es/proposal-set-methods/#sec-set.prototype.difference) method:

```js
var x = new Set(["a","b","c","t"]);
var y = new Set(["d","a","t","e","g"]);

var z = y.difference(x) // [ "d", "e", "g" ]
```

This is [currently working behind flags](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_set_difference) in some browsers, and being developed by others.

[image: Demo]

*In the meantime*, you can [polyfill any of the new set methods via npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/set.prototype.difference) or checkout [MDN's implementation of basic set operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#implementing_basic_set_operations)

#### Further Reading

- [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/1366033)
- [javascript - Remove all elements contained in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957348/1366033)
- [How to get the difference between two arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/1366033)
- [JavaScript get elements from an object array that are not in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50836835/1366033)