# What is the fastest order of magnitude that array subtraction can be implemented in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, algorithm

I want a function, subtract, that will take two arrays, and return all of the elements in array 1 that are not in array 2.

what is the fastest that this can be implemented in js? Is it o(n)?

Comment: what are in those arrays? are they deep objects or just values?

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963281/javascript-algorithm-to-find-elements-in-array-that-are-not-in-another-array . As you have to traverse both arrays once it's O(n)

Comment: Just a note, it will only be `O(n)` if they are both sorted, otherwise you end up with an `O(n^2)` operation.

Comment: It's o(n^2) because `indexOf` is o(n) aswell. I'm not sure whether sorting would make it O(n)

Comment: @regality and Raynos ~ apparently it can be done in o(n) .. See Adrian's answer

Comment: @Raynos wanted you to be tagged as well. Just FYI:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, faster O(n) time, but double memory (still linear), is to create your own hashmap implementation.

Create a hash function. Do a loop through one array and hash all elements. Store (hash, object) pair in another array, call it hash array. Now loop through array 2, and hash each element. Let the hash be the position in hash array, so you can see if you have a collision. If you have a collision check if the object in hash array is the same as the object in current array (that you're looping over).

Comment: In the js implementation, is it still o(n)?

Comment: @ZacharyBurt yes; afterall you're doing the implementation so you have control over it. It's 2 for loops: o(n) + o(n) = n(n) runtime. You need an extra o(n) of memory for the hashmap, and that's again 2*o(n)=o(n)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hash table implementation (using a javascript object as the hash) that is more than 100 times faster (in Chrome) with larger arrays than the brute force lookups using `indexOf()`.

```
function subtract3(one, two) {
    var hash = {}, result = [], i, len;
    // fill hash with members of second array for easy lookup
    for (i = 0, len = two.length; i < len; i++) {
        hash[two[i]] = true;
    }

    // cycle through first array and find ones that are not in two
    for (i = 0, len = one.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (!(one[i] in hash)) {
            result.push(one[i]);
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

Here's a jsperf test comparing this option with a couple other options: http://jsperf.com/array-subtraction

Comment: @Raynos - yes that is correct.  I was assuming this was an array of strings or numbers.  The OP did not specify.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generically solve this for O(n) unless you want to restrict your arrays to objects that can be serialized to strings

```
function substract(one, two) {
    var result = []
    for (var i = 0, len = one.length; i < len; i++) {
        var value = one[i]
        if (two.indexOf(value) === -1) {
            result.push(value)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Or if you want to use array iterators

```
function substract(one, two) {
    return one.filter(function (value) {
        return two.indexOf(value) === -1
    })
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond, but using indexOf guarantees a minimum n^2 runtime.