# JavaScript get elements from an object array that are not in another

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm new in JavaScript programming and I have two object arrays that have the following structure:

```
myFirstObjArray = [{foo: 1, bar: 1}, {foo: 3, bar: 3}, {foo: 4, bar: 5}];
mySecondObjArray = [{foo: 2}, {foo: 4}, {foo: 5}];
```

I need to get two separate arrays containing the values of key `foo`, the first containing the ones that are in the first array but not in the second, based on the value of key `foo`, and the second that are in `mySecondObjArray` but not in `myFirstObjArray`.

Is there a way to do this without

```
for(i=0;i<myFirstObjArray.length;i++)
   for(j=0;j<mySecondObjArray .length;j++)
      {...build first array here}

for(i=0;i<mySecondObjArray .length;i++)
   for(j=0;j<myFirstObjArray.length;j++)
      {...build second array here}
```

? Perhaps my question is a duplicate one that I didn't find, so please be gentle.

Expected output:

```
firstArray = [{foo: 1}, {foo: 3}];
secondArray = [{foo: 2}, {foo: 5}];
```

Comment: add your expected output here

Comment: @GeorgeBailey updated my question

Comment: @Dana: I added answer in ES5 to support all browsers including IE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: In most languages this is called something along the lines of "array diff".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can simply filter one array's elements by setting the condition based on other array's elements like.

```js
var myFirstObjArray = [{foo: 1, bar: 1}, {foo: 3, bar: 3}, {foo: 4, bar: 5}],
    mySecondObjArray = [{foo: 2}, {foo: 4}, {foo: 5}],
    
    firstArray  = myFirstObjArray.filter(o=> !mySecondObjArray.some(i=> i.foo === o.foo));
    
    secondArray  = mySecondObjArray.filter(o=> !myFirstObjArray.some(i=> i.foo === o.foo));
    
    console.log(firstArray.map(o=> {return {'foo' :  o.foo}}))
    console.log(secondArray.map(o=> {return {'foo' :  o.foo}}))
```

Ps:

The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. And I've added a function which just checks if `foo` property exists in the other array with the same value to be able to filter from the first array.

At the end you can use `.map` to filter out the desired key value pairs

Hope that makes sense

Read more about [**`.some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [**`filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: First array should contain only `foo` properties, so OP propably needs to read about `map` too

Comment: Does not provide the expected output

Comment: this helped me, thank you
`allRoles?.filter((r) => !userRoles?.some((ur) => ur.id === r.id)).map((role)`

Answer (score 10):

Here is a small solution with just `filter` and a `map` with the `foo` attribute.

```js
const myFirstObjArray = [{foo: 1, bar: 1}, {foo: 3, bar: 3}, {foo: 4, bar: 5}];
const mySecondObjArray = [{foo: 2}, {foo: 4}, {foo: 5}];

const exclude = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.filter(o1 => arr2.map(o2 => o2.foo).indexOf(o1.foo) === -1);

console.log(exclude(myFirstObjArray, mySecondObjArray));
console.log(exclude(mySecondObjArray, myFirstObjArray));
```

Comment: Prefer `includes` to `indefOf`

Answer (score 2):

ES5 without using fat arrow,

```js
var myFirstObjArray = [{foo: 1, bar: 1}, {foo: 3, bar: 3}, {foo: 4, bar: 5}],
    mySecondObjArray = [{foo: 2}, {foo: 4}, {foo: 5}],
    
    firstArray  = myFirstObjArray.filter(function(o) { return !mySecondObjArray.some(function(i) { return i.foo === o.foo})});
     
    secondArray  = mySecondObjArray.filter(function(o) { return !myFirstObjArray.some(function(i) { return i.foo === o.foo})});
    
    console.log(firstArray)
    console.log(secondArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter by look up.

```js
const unique = a => o => !a.some(({ foo }) => o.foo === foo);

var first = [{foo: 1, bar: 1}, {foo: 3, bar: 3}, {foo: 4, bar: 5}],
    second = [{foo: 2}, {foo: 4}, {foo: 5}],
    uniqueFirst = first.filter(unique(second)),
    uniqueSecond = second.filter(unique(first));
    
console.log(uniqueFirst);
console.log(uniqueSecond);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a reusable function to prevent code duplication. Just switch over to the function parameter. Also note that the inner loop is simple `for` loop so that we can use `break` and avoid unnecessary checks.

```js
var firstArray = [];
var secondArray = [];
var myFirstObjArray = [{foo: 1, bar: 1}, {foo: 3, bar: 3}, {foo: 4, bar: 5}];
var mySecondObjArray = [{foo: 2}, {foo: 4}, {foo: 5}];

function difference(myFirstObjArray, mySecondObjArray){
  var firstArray = [];
  myFirstObjArray.forEach((obj)=>{
   var match = false;
   for(var i=0; i<mySecondObjArray.length; i++){
     var secondObj = mySecondObjArray[i];
     if(obj.foo === secondObj.foo){
       match = true;
       break;
     }
   }
   if(!match){
     firstArray.push({'foo': obj.foo});
   }
  });
  return firstArray;
}


console.log(difference(myFirstObjArray, mySecondObjArray));

console.log(difference(mySecondObjArray, myFirstObjArray));
```