# Javascript find index of missing elements of two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following JavaScript where I have some lists:

```
var deleteLinks = $(".remove-button .remove-from-cart");
deleteLinks.on('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("registered: " + deleteLinks);
    var currentHTML = $('.product');
    var currentText = $('.product .product-details .name-header');  
    var newHTML ;
        $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
              newHTML = $(data).find('.product .product-details .name-header'); 
              for(i = 0; i  < newHTML.length; i++){
                  console.log("new: " + newHTML[i].innerText);
                  console.log("old: " + currentText[i].innerText);
              }
          }
    });
});
```

The variable `currentHTML` contains an array of divs which are a container. The `currentText` contains an array of each container's name. The variable received in the AJAX response (`newHTML`) contains an array of names. This array is updated after some user interaction. One or more entries of the `currentText` variable may be missing and I want to find the indices of them so I can remove them from the container (`currentHTML`).

Can someone help me to find the indices of the missing elements between `currentText` and the retrieved data (`newHTML`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript algorithm to find elements in array that are not in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963281/javascript-algorithm-to-find-elements-in-array-that-are-not-in-another-array)

Comment: He wanted to compare two separate lists, then if those two had a match regardless of list 3. Check list 3 for the position of the item.

Answer (score 2):

To compare two array's value's there is many different approaches to simply see if a value is in another array. You might use `array.indexOf(value)` to return a position of an element in another array, if the result is greater than expected `-1`, it is present or the opposite missing. You might also use `array.includes(value)`, and another way is to simply see if a value is not present by using `!array.includes(value)`.

So knowing we can use `!array.includes(value)` to see if an array does not include a value. We must now loop through one array to grab entries and compare against another array for items that are not in the other array. We will use `array.forEach()` for this. We could possibly design more recursive functions using `array.some()`, but I am just trying to give you some simple examples.

> Example 1.

```js
// Data
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // Array A
let b = [1, 0, 9, 3, 5]; // Array B

// Basic principals
function check(a, b) {
    // Loop through A using array.some() => value
    a.forEach(value => {
        // B did not include value
        if (!b.includes(value)) {
            // Output
            console.log("B doesn't have", value, "at position", a.indexOf(value), "in A")
        }
    });
    // Loop through B using array.some() => value
    b.forEach(value => {
        // A did not include value
        if (!a.includes(value)) {
            // Output
            console.log("A doesn't have", value, "at position", b.indexOf(value), "in B")
        }
    });
}

// We are checking both Arrays A and B
check([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 0, 9, 3, 5]);
```

> Example 2

Instead of just outputting to the console for demonstration purposes let's make a prototype for an array element, and then call a comparative function against array **B**. We will return an array with the `[value, position]` if that value is not in array **B** but indeed in array **A**.

```js
// Data
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; // Array A
let b = [1, 0, 9, 3, 5]; // Array B

/*
    Check an array for non-duplicates against another array.
    If the value of item in array A is present in array B,
    return [false, -1]. If value of item in array A is
    not present in B, return value and position of value
    in array A.
 */

Array.prototype.check = function(b) {
    /*
    * return if true
    *   [value, position]
    * else
    *   [false, -1]
    * */
    return a.map(v => {
       return (!b.includes(v) ? [v, a.indexOf(v)] : [false, -1])
    })
};

// Array A is checking against array B
console.log(a.check(b));

/*  Output:
    (A checking against B)
    [
      [ false, -1 ], // Array element 1 found in B
      [ 2, 1 ],  // Array element 2 not found in B, and has position 1 in A
      [ false, -1 ],  // Array element 3 found in B
      [ 4, 3 ], // Array element 4 not found in B, and has position 3 in A
      [ false, -1 ] // Array element 5 found in B
    ]
*/
```

Comment: I had such a solution too, but the 2 is contained in both arrays. I only want to find those indices that are in array 1, but not contained in array 2, for example: [1,2,3,4,5] and [2,1,5,4] should give a missing 3 and thus I want to get the index of 3 in the first array

Comment: Sorry, I was confused at first my bad. I fixed it, I got it right now 3rd edit lol.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can use [_.difference](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#difference) to solve this in one line.

```js
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  b = ['b'],
  result = [];
_.difference(a, b).forEach(function(t) {result.push(a.indexOf(t))});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of multidimensional arrays? Let's say that every array object contains id and value properties.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have unique elements in an array `A` and only one occurrence in the array `B`. We can just use set to add all the elements of array `A` and remove the elements from the set when you iterate over Array `B`. Use `findIndex` to look up for elements remaining in the set.

```
const a = [1,2,3,4,5];
const b = [2,1,5,4];
let set = new Set();
a.forEach(ele => set.add(ele));
b.forEach(ele => {
  if(set.has(ele)){
    set.remove(ele);
  }
});
let res = [];
for(let s of set) {
  if(a.findIndex(s) !== -1) {
    res.push({
     arr:  a,
     pos: a.findeIndex(s)
    });
  }else {
    res.push({
     arr:  b,
     pos: b.findeIndex(s)
    });
  }
}
```

The `res` array contains the index and the array in which the element is present.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your code, you need to compare innerText of the two objects and find the indices of missing elemnts.

```
var missing_indices = [];
for(var i=0;i<currentText.length;i++){
    var found = false;
    for(var j=0;j<newHTML.length;j++){
        if(currentText[i].innerText == newHTML[j].innerText){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found){
        missing_indices.push(i);
    }
}
```

Then use missing_indices to remove missing elements from currentHTML