# Find last row with Data in Column D starting the search at Row 4 in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to find a way to find the last row with data in Column D.  I also want the search to start at Row 4.

I'm really struggling and would appericate any help please.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116043/get-the-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column-in-google-sheets)?

Comment: Try getColumnHeight() here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55425107/7215091

Comment: I thought that this thread might be useful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639/7108653

Answer (score 2):

### You can refer to this code:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rowOffset = 3;
  var count = sheet.getRange('D4:D').getDisplayValues().flat().filter(String).length;
  var lastRow = count+rowOffset;
  Logger.log(lastRow);
```

### What it does?

1. Select Range `D4:D` and get its value, since you want to get the last row with data in column D starting at row 4.
2. Use array.flat() to change 2-d array into 1-d array.
3. Use array.filter() to remove empty values. Then get it's array length
4. To get the last row index, Use the cell count that has data which we obtained in step 3 and add it to 3 (start offset since we start our search at row 4)

### Note:

- This solution will only work assuming you don't have empty rows in between.

### Output:

[image]

```
Execution log
2:01:53 AM  Notice  Execution started
2:01:54 AM  Info    13.0
2:01:55 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered an issue

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to find the last value in a column, but here is one. See if this helps!

```
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('Insert Sheet URL Here');
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Insert Sheet Name Here - e.g. Sheet1');
  const lastSheetRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  let lastColumnRow = 'This column is empty';
  let reversedColumnValues = sheet.getRange(1, 4, lastSheetRow).getValues().reverse();
  for (index in reversedColumnValues) {
    if (reversedColumnValues[index][0] != '') {
      lastColumnRow = lastSheetRow - index;
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(lastColumnRow);
}
```

This Apps Script Video may help you out too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Po1QElOFPk