# JS/ES6/lodash find index of missing elements of two multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, ecmascript-6

Assuming that I have 2 multidimensional arrays of objects

```
const products = [
  {
    id: 1
    name: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'ipsum'
  }
];

const tmp_products = [
  {
    id: 1
    name: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    name: 'porros'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'ipsum'
  },
  {
    id: 105,
    name: 'dolor'
  },
  {
    id: 32,
    name: 'simet'
  }
];
```

What is the correct way to find the missing indexes by `id` property?
I'm expecting an output such as `[1,3,4]` since those objects are not present in `products`

I found a similar question but applied to plain arrays:
[Javascript find index of missing elements of two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613907/javascript-find-index-of-missing-elements-of-two-arrays)

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  b = ['b'],
  result = [];
_.difference(a, b).forEach(function(t) {result.push(a.indexOf(t))});

console.log(result);
```

I'd like to use ES6 or lodash to get this as short as possible

Comment: No, I need missing indexes not missing ids, so I'm expecting `[1,3,4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` function to get the list of missing products' index.

Inside `reduce` callback, you can check if the product is included in `products` array or not using `Array.prototype.some` and based on that result, you can decide to add the `product index` or not.

```js
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'ipsum'
  }
];

const tmp_products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'lorem'
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    name: 'porros'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'ipsum'
  },
  {
    id: 105,
    name: 'dolor'
  },
  {
    id: 32,
    name: 'simet'
  }
];

const missingIndex = tmp_products.reduce((acc, curV, curI) => {
  if (!products.some((item) => item.id === curV.id && item.name === curV.name)) {
    acc.push(curI);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(missingIndex);
```

Comment: I've changed to this as the accepted answer since other solutions are comparing the whole object. In this way, I can take care only about product ids and compare them based on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sets to do it quickly:

```
const productIds = new Set(products.map(v => v.id));
const inds = tmp_products
    .map((v, i) => [v, i])
    .filter(([v, i]) => !productIds.has(v.id))
    .map(([v, i]) => i);
inds // [1, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

With lodash you could use `differenceWith`:

```js
_(tmp_products)
  .differenceWith(products, _.isEqual)
  .map(prod => tmp_products.indexOf(prod))
  .value()
```

This may not be great for performance, but it depends on how many items you have. With the size of your arrays this should perform ok.

Comment: Nice solution. I will handle an array with no more than 10 objects so this fits perfectly. Besides this is the clearest one I'm also able to easily get missing product ids by doing _(tmp_products).differenceWith(products, _.isEqual).map(prod => tmp_products.id).value()