# Function that returns difference of two arrays of strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc)

I need help with devising a function that will return the difference between two arrays of strings in Javascript (jQuery is acceptable as well).

I am basically looking for a function that calculates array A **minus** B.

So if we have the followin"

```
A = ['Istanbul', 'Hong Kong', 'Berlin'];
B = ['Berlin', 'Bonn'];
```

Calling `diff = minus(A,B)` should result with `diff` being populated with the following values `['Istanbul', 'Hong Kong']`

I do not want to use an additional library like `JS Set`.

Please help with suggestions ...

Comment: Have you made any attempts to solve this already? If you have, what went wrong, what would you like us to help with? A part of the problem, or the whole of the problem?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
function diff(A, B) {
    return A.filter(function (a) {
        return B.indexOf(a) == -1;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The fastest would probably be a regular loop

```js
var A = ['Istanbul', 'Hong Kong', 'Berlin'],
    B = ['Berlin', 'Bonn'],
    C = [];

for (var i=A.length; i--;) {
   if (B.indexOf(A[i]) === -1) 
       C.push(A[i]);
}

console.log(C);
```

The most elegant is opinion-based, but something like

```js
var A = ['Istanbul', 'Hong Kong', 'Berlin'],
    B = ['Berlin', 'Bonn'];

var C = A.filter(x => !B.includes(x));

console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
var minus = function ( a, b ) {
    return a.filter(function ( name ) {
        return b.indexOf( name ) === -1;
    });
};
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SjF9p/