# Subtract arrays - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have arrays like;

```
var john = { name: "John Smith", age: 23 };
var mary = { name: "Mary Key", age: 18 };
var bob = { name: "Bob-small", age: 6 };
var people = [john, mary, bob];

var john2 = { name: "John Smith", age: 23 };
var people2 = [john2];
```

What I would like to do is subtract people2 from people and get result;

```
[mary, bob];
```

How can I achieve this?
TIA

Comment: [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Read [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc)

Answer (score 8):

The difference of two sets, A and B, is defined as the set of all those elements of A which are not in B. If we implement it naively, computing the difference of two sets of sizes `m` and `n` respectively would take `O(m * n)` time. Not very efficient:

```js
const john1 = { name: "John Smith", age: 23 };
const john2 = { name: "John Smith", age: 23 };
const mary = { name: "Mary Key", age: 18 };
const bob = { name: "Bob-small", age: 6 };

const people1 = [john1, mary, bob];
const people2 = [john2];

const eqPerson = (p, q) => p.name === q.name && p.age === q.age;

const result = people1.filter(p => people2.every(q => !eqPerson(p, q)));

console.log(result); // [mary, bob]
```

---

Fortunately, there's a faster way to compute the set difference for large sets using hashing.

```js
const john1 = { name: "John Smith", age: 23 };
const john2 = { name: "John Smith", age: 23 };
const mary = { name: "Mary Key", age: 18 };
const bob = { name: "Bob-small", age: 6 };

const people1 = [john1, mary, bob];
const people2 = [john2];

const hashPerson = ({ name, age }) => `${name} ${age}`;

const hashSet = new Set(people2.map(hashPerson));

const result = people1.filter(p => !hashSet.has(hashPerson(p)));

console.log(result); // [mary, bob]
```

The advantage is that creating a hash set takes `O(n)` time and calculating the difference takes `O(m)` time. Hence in total it only takes `O(m + n)` time instead of `O(m * n)` time. In addition, you can reuse the hash set in the future.

Comment: Nice explanation, Yes I don't understand `arguments.length` where does `arguments`  come? May be very silly question but I am kinda new to Web-stuffs. Can you also tell me what does `hasOwnProperty` means?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments

Answer (score 5):

Here is an easy solution:

```
var diff = people.filter(function(item) {
  return !people2.some(function(test){
    return test.name === item.name && test.age === item.age;
  });
});
```

Make sure the function passed to `people2.some` correctly checks that the two objects are equal, since `==` would fail, as you have references to different objects with identical properties.

Answer (score 0):

So, here goes the final running code. Copy , paste it and check for the output.It is first of all separating the strings (comma-separation). Then it is comparing them individually . Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/DXRZ4/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
        var a = new Array(); var i=1; var people = new Array();
        function fun() {
            var str = "john,john,bob",
                l = str.split(",");
            for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
                a[i] = l[i];
                // this will show the comma separated strings
                document.writeln(l[i]);
            }
            for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
                t=a[i]; 
                j=a[i+1];
                if((a[i]==a[i+1]) || (a[i]==a[i+2])) {
                    // it will store the position of string which are same
                    p=i; 
                }
            }
            for(i=0; i<3; i++) { 
                if(p!=i){
                    document.writeln("Subtracted Strings are:-");
                    document.writeln(l[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
  <body>
    <input type="button" name="b1" onClick="fun()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for the reader instead of expecting them to copy/paste your code?