# How to compare two lists - set difference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, set-difference

I'm sure this is very easy (I'm a beginner!), but I couldn't find a solution.

I would like to import two arrays from .csv-files, then compare the two and return the values which DO appear on List1 and are NOT on List2. So List1 minus List2 = my result.

List1 could look like: 100,200,300,400 and List2 100,200. I would then like to return 300,400.

(If List 2 should happen to have some values which are not in List 1, I'd like it to run anyway and not give an error, but I figure it wouldn't?)

Thanks in advance for any tips/pointers or code, should you be so kind :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc)

Comment: do you want speed or simplicity?

Comment: Definitely simplicity! Each array will have less than 50 values.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 2 strings with `,` separated values like

```
var a= "100, 200, 400";
var b = "100, 200, 300";
```

You could concatenate the values like, using `String.split` convert them into an array:

```
var items = (a +","+ b).split(',');
```

And then could do this in several ways one is using `Array.prototype.reduce` like

```
items.reduce(function(a,c){  var count = a.filter(function(item){ return item ===c; }).length; if(count<1 ) a.push(c); return a;},[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
var array1 = [100,200,300,400];
var array2 = [200,100,400];
function array_diff(arr1,arr2)
{
    var x = Math.max(arr1.length,arr2.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if(typeof arr1[i] !== 'undefined' && arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) !== -1)
            arr1.splice(i,1);
        if(typeof arr2[i] !== 'undefined' && arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) !== -1)
            arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]),1);
    }
    return arr1;
}
console.log(array_diff(array1,array2));
```

I tried to avoid using `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.reduce` because they are not compatible with older browsers. As far as I know, `Array.prototype.splice` has better support.

If you're looking for speed gains, I could be wrong but, I think sorting the arrays beforehand would speed up `indexOf`.

http://jsfiddle.net/0tcyam2f/1/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers!

I'm afraid this code is a little over my understanding still, so I just tested the various options, and the one that seems to give the desired result without any error messages is the one from [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc) , as rightly pointed out by Vache, that is:

```
A = [100,200,300];
B = [100,200,500];

diff_set = {
    ar : {},
    diff : Array(),
    remove_set : function(a) { ar = a; return this; },
    remove: function (el) {
        if(ar.indexOf(el)<0) this.diff.push(el);
    }
};

A.forEach(diff_set.remove_set(B).remove,diff_set);
C = diff_set.diff;
```

originally posted by [Xavi Ivars](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200472/xavi-ivars)

Thanks for providing answers!! Much appreciated :-)