# Compare two lists and remove common elements using angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, html, list

I am having 2 lists like below

> list1 =
>   ['option1','option2','option3','option4','option5','option6','option7'];
>
> list2 = ['option3', 'option4', 'option7'];

I want the list to be

> listFinal = ['option1','option2','option5','option6','option7'];

Please give me the suggestion using angular js how to solve this using filter

Tried to use this code to solve this using filter but unable to succeed.

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
   return function(collection, keyname) {
      var output = [], 
          keys = [];

  angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var key = item[keyname];
      if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          keys.push(key);
          output.push(item);


     }
      });
      return output;
   };
});
```

Comment: You could use `underscore`/`loadash` js for doing such a thing..they had an various sets of method for doing this

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you really want a filter here. This is something that you should probably solve outside of Angular. If you're willing to add lodash to your project, you could do this:

```
var diff = _.difference(array1, array2);
```

If you must use a filter, you could try something like this?

```
app.filter('difference', function() {
     return function(input, diff_array) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            if (diff_array.indexOf(input[i]) == -1) {
                result.push(input[i]);
            }
        }
        return result;
     }
 }
```

Note that if you do this, your template has to look something like:

```
{{ input | difference:diff_arr }}
```

I haven't actually tested any of this, but this should be the general idea. I concur with Phillip that this really isn't something you should try to solve in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is an "array/set difference". There are many questions on StackOverflow asking about this already. This is not related to Angular.js, but is an problem with an algorithmic solution. Just to add  bit of interesting material, a "naive" solution runs in `O(nlogn)` which would be:

- Sort the two lists/arrays from lowests to highest
- Traverse each array setting the internal pointer to 0 initially, compare the elements. If the element in Array A is larger than the on in Array B advance the pointer by 1 in Array B, else B, else if they are equal, remove the result from the array and advance both pointers

[What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc)

[JavaScript array difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Comment: Cant we do the same thing using filter

Comment: Yes just add this as a callback function into your filter. The function is called whenever the filter is used. You don't need to (or have to actually since there is none) "angular" way, just apply the filter when needed (I can't see from your code whether or not you are manipulating the view from the controller  or the DOM does some event and triggers a function)