# NodeJS - How to get specific elements from growing array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm using [Robots.js](https://github.com/ekalinin/robots.js) to getch the sitemaps from robots.txt files of a list of websites. Basically, I use QueryStream to query each site url from a MongoDB collection and pass it on Robots.js function to process.

```
var stream = Urls.find().stream();

stream.on('data', function(data) {
    // Fetch the urls from domain pool
    var url = data;   

 // Get Sitemaps
    parser.setUrl('http://' + url + '/robots.txt' || 'https://' + url + '/robots.txt', function(parser, success) {
        if (success) {
            parser.getSitemaps(function(sitemaps) {
                // The array keeps increasing after each url passed in
                console.log(sitemaps);
                // Did try this but not work
                sitemaps.length = 0;
            });
        }
    });
}).on('error', function(err) {
    // handle the error
    console.log(err);
}).on('close', function() {
    // the stream is closed
    console.log('End of database!');
});
```

The problem is it returns an array which keeps increasing each time an url passed in and proccessed, like:
`[url1/sitemap.xml], 
[url1/sitemap.xml, url2/sitemap.xml], 
[url1/sitemap.xml, url2/sitemap.xml, url3/sitemap.xml]`

while the ideal thing I want is
`[url1/sitemap.xml], 
[url2/sitemap.xml], 
[url3/sitemap.xml]` for each corresponding url passed in.

So my question is that is there any way to take the sitemap urls which match the given urls only? I've tried with `sitemaps.filter` to filter out but no luck.

Comment: Why not did you get last one of array? I think the success flag guarantees that.

Comment: I did think about it, but some sites has 1 sitemap, some has more, so taking the last one may be not enough.

Comment: I got it why you didn't do that. If that library doesn't support this feature, [difference of sets that is implemented in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1723220/4751310) is great solution for you. Save previous `sitemaps` as a variable and get difference of sets by executing with current `sitemaps`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually I found another way to fix the issue. It's really simple, I just need to create a new instance of Robot.js each time it got a new url, and it works like a charm now.