# Use one array of strings to splice another array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I have one array:

```
var array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

And another:

```
var array2 = ['two, 'four']
```

How can I remove all the strings from `array2` out of `array1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with [bitwise not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) `~` operator for checking.

> `~` is a [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT). It is perfect for use with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), because `indexOf` returns if found the index `0 ... n` and if not `-1`:
>
> ```
> value  ~value   boolean
> -1  =>   0  =>  false
>  0  =>  -1  =>  true
>  1  =>  -2  =>  true
>  2  =>  -3  =>  true
>  and so on
> ```

```js
var array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'],
    array2 = ['two', 'four'];

array1 = array1.filter(function (a) {
    return !~array2.indexOf(a);
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(array1, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: And what about `!~` ?

Comment: @RayonDabre bitwise negation operator, making code quite unreadable imho

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
array2.forEach(item => array1.splice(array1.indexOf(item),1));
```

Answer (score 0):

in jquery with inArray method:

```
for(array1)
  var idx = $.inArray(array1[i], array2);
  if (idx != -1) {//-1 not exists 
     array2.splice(idx, 1);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
var array2 = ['two', 'four']
    
array1 = array1.filter(function(item){
   return array2.indexOf(item) === -1
})
// ['one', 'three', 'four', 'five']

document.write(array1)
```