# How to match both the arrays in Angularjs and have to display matched one?

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I have user_id in two array, one is available user_id's for projects and other is selected user_id.

```
availableusers = ["00000000a447a9160c9d6b74", "000000005c05c11764445bdb"]
selected Users = ["000000005c05c11764445bdb"]
```

Now I need to match both the array and have to display matched in selected div and unmatched in availabe div.

How can I able to do this?

Comment: What is angularjs in this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723168/what-is-the-fastest-or-most-elegant-way-to-compute-a-set-difference-using-javasc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.availableusers = ["00000000a447a9160c9d6b74", "000000005c05c11764445bdb"]
  $scope.selectedUsers = ["000000005c05c11764445bdb"]

  $scope.matchUser = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.availableusers.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < $scope.selectedUsers.length; j++) {
      if ($scope.availableusers[i] === $scope.selectedUsers[j]) {
        $scope.matchUser.push($scope.availableusers[i]);
      }
    }

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span>Available users</span>
  <div ng-repeat="available in availableusers">{{available}}</div>
  <span>Selected Users</span>
  <div ng-repeat="selectUser in selectedUsers">{{selectUser}}</div>
  <span>Users</span>
  <div ng-repeat="Users in matchUser">{{Users}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you .. It working good now its displaying available users  and selected users. If i clicked any one in available it should be add in selected and have to remove in available.do u have any idea

Comment: I can help you. You need to write two function add and remove

Comment: Thank You. Problem Solved :)

Comment: if the answer I provided is correct please mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

```
var result=[];
 for(var i = 0 ;i<availableUsers.length;i++){
   if(availableusers[i] === selectedUsers[i])
     {
       result.push(availableusers[i]);
      }     
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.