# Remove Array Json object elements

Tags: node.js, arrays

Here I have two arrays

```
var arry1 = [{id:1,name:"muni"},{id:2,name:"Anji"}, {id:3,name:"vinod"},{id:4,name:"anil"}];

var arry2 = [{id:3},{id:1}];
```

I want the following results

```
arry1= [{id:2,name:"Anji"},{id:4,name:"anil"}]
```

Should be remove second selected elements in first array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove array of objects from another array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47017770/remove-array-of-objects-from-another-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove any element that is present in `arry2`. We can create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of id elements to filter out, this will be more efficient for larger arrays:

```js
var arry1 = [{id:1,name:"muni"},{id:2,name:"Anji"}, {id:3,name:"vinod"},{id:4,name:"anil"}];
var arry2 = [{id:3},{id:1}];

// Filter out any elements in arry1 that are also present in arry2, first create a Set of IDs to filter
const idsToFilter = new Set(arry2.map(el => el.id));
const result = arry1.filter(el => !idsToFilter.has(el.id));

console.log("Result:", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

While removing from an array, you should iterate backwards over it.

```js
for (let i = arry1.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
  ...
}
```

This ensures that no elements are skipped after an element is removed. See also [this other question for more info on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop).

Now for each element of arry1 we want to check whether it should be removed.

```js
let idsToRemove = arry2.map(e => e.id); // [3, 1]

for (let i = arry1.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
  if (idsToRemove.includes(arry1[i].id) {
    // it should be removed
    arry1.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Something like the above should then work for your problem. For easier understanding of the code, I first mapped arry2 to only the IDs, but of course you can also use another loop to see whether there is a match. The most important take-away is that **to safely remove from an array while iterating it, you need to iterate from the last to the first element**.

Comment: As a general note, it's very helpful if you share your current code attempt. That way more targeted feedback/help can be given!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work, here filter will filter out only those array element which doesn't exist in arry2

```
var myArray = arry1.filter(ar => !arry2.find(el => (el.id === ar.id) ))
```