# Viewing all disabled Eslint rules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

I'm using the recommended Eslint rules with a lot of overrides. I assumed the recommended rules were sufficiently strict, but I found some useful rules that weren't enabled. How can I view all the rules that are available but disabled? I want to be able to read each of the rules and maybe manually enable them.

Comment: you're gonna need a list of all enabled rules and a list of all rules, then subtract enabled from all [What is the fastest or most elegant way to compute a set difference using Javascript arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36504668/12101554)

Answer (score 1):

You can view all the rules [on the ESLint Website](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/). However, ESLint has other rules that come from plugins you might use.

To view all of these, you can use [`eslint-find-rules`](https://github.com/sarbbottam/eslint-find-rules), which can show plugin rules and other available rules.

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "eslint-find-option-rules": "eslint-find-rules [option] <file> [flag]"
  }
  ...
}
```

The `-a` flag is probably what you're looking for:

```
eslint-find-rules -a .eslintrc.js
```